# Why prettier-plugin-tailwindcss does not sort my classes on my WordPress project

Tags: php, wordpress, tailwind-css, prettier, prettier-vscode

I don't know if the answer is pretty obvious or not, but I can't seem to make this [prettier-plugin-tailwindcss : Automatic Class Sorting with Prettier](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier) work on any of my projects using **PHP FILES** / **WordPress**.

I've installed the plugin and ran the shortcut to make prettier work since nothing else seems necessary as mentioned in the link above :

> This plugin follows Prettier’s autoloading convention, so as long as you’ve got Prettier set up in your project, it’ll start working automatically as soon as it’s installed.

Everything works perfectly fine in ALL other files such as : **scss, js, html**.

But once I try running the added prettier-plugin in one of my **PHP** files, only the basic prettier plugin is applied and none of my classes are getting sorted.

I've installed and ran this prettier-plugin-tailwindcss in other projects aswell to test it out and like mentionned before, as long as it is **not a PHP file**, the plugin **works perfectly** and sort all the classes like it should.

I'm working with:

- VsCode v1.74.3
- macOS Ventura 13.0.1
- WordPress v6.1.1
- Prettier v2.8.3
- prettier-plugin-tailwindcss v0.2.1

So what am I missing here?

Why doesn't this [prettier-plugin-tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier) work on any of my **PHP files**?

Answer (score 0):

It does work. You just need to tell prettier what parser to use.
Example:

```
prettier --parser html templates/components/
```